# Django form.is_valid() failing class based views - Form, SingleObject, DetailMixins

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two apps, here we will call them blog and comments.

Comments has a Comment model. Blog has a blog Model. Comments has a CommentForm. Blog has a DetailView.

I want my CommentForm to appear on by Blog DetailView, so people can submit comments from the blog detail page.

The form renders OK - it makes a POST request, it redirects to get_success_url() but (I've added a couple of prints to views.py - see below) in testing in views.py to see if the form data is received I see the form.is_valid() path is not met, and I don't understand why.

I'm essentially trying to follow this, the 'alternative better solution':
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview

**blog/views.py**

```
class CommentLooker(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm
    model = blog

    def get_object(self):
        #self.team = get_object_or_404(team, team_id=self.kwargs['team_id'])
        #queryset_list = blog.objects.filter(team = self.team)
        team_id_ = self.kwargs.get("team_id")
        blog_id_ = self.kwargs.get("blog_id")
        return get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(CommentLooker, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blogs:teams')

class blogDisplay(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        view = blogFromteamContentView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        view = CommentLooker.as_view()
        return view(request,*args,**kwargs)

class blogFromteamContentView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = blog
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_detail.html'
    # override get_object so we can use blog_id when we use this class in urls.py
    # otherwise DetailViews expect 'pk' which defaults to the primary key of the model.

    def get_object(self):
        team_id_ = self.kwargs.get("team_id")
        blog_id_ = self.kwargs.get("blog_id")
        return get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(blogFromteamContentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        team_id_ = self.kwargs.get("team_id")
        blog_id_ = self.kwargs.get("blog_id")

        # get the list of blogs for a given blog id and team id combination.
        context['queryset'] = get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)

        # get and set things related to ability to associate comments to a blog.
        initial_data = {
                "content_type": blog.get_content_type,
                "object_id": blog.blog_id
            }
        comments        = blog.comments # uses the @property set in this class.
        comment_form    = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            print(comment_form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print('invalido!')
        context['comment_form'] = comment_form
        return context
```

**blog/models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    team= models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE)
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name='Blog Name')
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
path('teams/<int:team_id>/blogs/<int:blog_id>/', blog.blogDisplay.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

**blog_detail.html**

```
<div> 
<p class="lead"> Comments </p>
<form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ comment_form}} 
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
<hr/>
{% for comment in blog.comments.all %}

<blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer"> {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </footer>
</blockquote>

<hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

**comments/forms.py**

from django import forms

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    object_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    parent_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

edit:

after using print(comment_form.errors):

object_id

Enter a whole number.

suggesting my initial_data might be the problem. In fact both content_type and object_id in my initial_data were problems. I was asking for blog.blog_id - I.e. using the class, not an instance. So I changed

**get_context_data:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
context = super(blogFromteamContentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
team_id_ = self.kwargs.get("team_id")
blog_id_ = self.kwargs.get("blog_id")

# get the list of blogs for a given blog id and team id combination.
context['queryset_list_recs'] = get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)

instance = get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)
initial_data = {
        "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
        "object_id": blog_id_
    }
```

and to my **views.py:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        print('valido')
        c_type = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
            user = self.request.user,
            content_type = content_type,
            object_id = obj_id,
            content = content_data
        )
    else:
        print('postinvalido!')
    return super(CommentLooker, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This (inappropriate print statements aside) now appears to give intended behaviour.

Comment: I assume you mean that you are not getting to the line `if comment_form.is_valid(): ` in `blogFromteamContentView.get_context_data`? On a POST you are using the `CommentLooker` view and not that view

Comment: of course, silly of me. thank you. I'll focus on the post method of CommentLooker instead then. 

I'm not sure how post gets it's context - i.e. is this where I will save the form.

Comment: So if I define initial data and add 
`comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST, None, initial=initial_data)`
to the post method of `CommentLooker`, the comment_form fails `comment_form.is_valid()`

Just now my assumption is there's some bug making my form invalid - once that is fixed I would then add `Comment.objects.get_or_create([fields]) to the post method of CommentLooker, in order to save the comments.

Comment: `print(form.errors)` gives me: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>object_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a whole number.</li></ul></li></ul>` so I guess the problem is with my initial_data. I'll edit a clarification into the main body.

Comment: Main question text has been updated with a nearly-solution. I'm not sure about instantiating a CommentForm(self.request.POST) inside the post method of CommentLooker. Isn't the form being passed in already? It's unclear to me how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using print(comment_form.errors):

- object_id
- List item

Enter a whole number.

suggesting my initial_data might be the problem. In fact both content_type and object_id in my initial_data were problems. I was asking for blog.blog_id - I.e. using the class, not an instance. So I changed

**get_context_data:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
context = super(blogFromteamContentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
team_id_ = self.kwargs.get("team_id")
blog_id_ = self.kwargs.get("blog_id")

# get the list of blogs for a given blog id and team id combination.
context['queryset_list_recs'] = get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)

instance = get_object_or_404(blog, blog_id=blog_id_, team=team_id_)
initial_data = {
        "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
        "object_id": blog_id_
    }
```

and to my **views.py**:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        print('valido')
        c_type = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
            user = self.request.user,
            content_type = content_type,
            object_id = obj_id,
            content = content_data
        )
    else:
        print('postinvalido!')
    return super(CommentLooker, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This (inappropriate print statements aside) now appears to give intended behaviour. I'm unclear why an instance of CommentForm needs to be created inside the post method - it feels like I'm doing something wrong here.